# Unable to figure out the file/folders permission in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, filesystem, users, user-management

I am new to Linux and trying to learn the basics on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS pc.

The problem I am facing is related to giving file permission for other users.

Basically, I have set up two user accounts-

-gaurav (Main account)

uid=1000(gaurav) gid=1000(gaurav) groups=1000(gaurav),27(sudo),1001(Superheroes)

-Ironman (practice account)

uid=1001(Ironman) gid=1001(Superheroes) groups=1001(Superheroes),27(sudo)

I have created a random file "Automobiles.txt" in the user account of Ironman (/home/Ironman/) and gave the following rights-

chmod 774 Automobiles.txt

This should normally give the users from the group "Superheroes" the right to view and edit. However, when I switch to my Main account, I get permission denied error.

Yes, I did log out from my Main account before opening the file.

The only way I managed to set the permission for my Main account was by giving the full permission to the Home folder of Ironman account.

gaurav@Linux:~$ ls -l /home/

total 8

drwxr-xr-x 22 gaurav  gaurav      4096 Jun  8 23:46 gaurav

drwxrwxr-- 16 Ironman Superheroes 4096 Jun  8 23:40 Ironman

With this, I can now view and edit the file. But this is not ideal and I would only like to share specific files and folder.

Now, even if I set the rights to read only for the file Automobiles, I can still copy and edit the files from the main account.

Can you please advise if I am doing something wrong?

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice (not only with Linux systems) is to create a group and a folder writable for the group.

For example.
The group of car fans is `carfans` and the folder will be `/home/Carfans`
the user accounts concerned will be added to the group and will receive de facto write permissions to the folder.

```
sudo groupadd carfans
sudo mkdir /home/Carfans

# Apply filesystem security
sudo chgrp -R carfans /home/Carfans
sudo chmod -R 2775 /home/Carfans
## 2 turns on the setGID, created items inside the folder will inherit the same group
## 77 read write & execute for owner (root) and group (carfans)
## 5 read & execute for others (set 0 if no other allowed)

# Add the users to the group
sudo usermod -a -G carfans gaurav
sudo usermod -a -G carfans Ironman
```